# Socks4 Client/Server implementation

Tags: beginner, c, networking, proxy

I implemented a basic Socks4 client and server which can handle `CONNECT` requests only right now also without identfication protocol support.

I've tested it with a simple `ncat` echo server which works but I would like to have a review of my:

- project structure
- filenaming/code splitting
- naming/design of structures
- error handling
- and of course the code.
- handling multiple connections (thread for each session? threadpool?)

I tried to create a flexible `socks_config` and `socks` structure but I am not sure if I succeeded. I really want to avoid having `socks4_client` and `socks4_server` to achive a simple and small interface for the user, where the functions returns if it is the wrong "object type".

I've read about the usage of poll and select with many connections which is not recommended so I stick to the threaded-way but thread creation is expensive. Would be nice to hear what you think is right.

I also am not sure if my usage of poll is stupid or correct or could be better.

As you will notice the accept function is quite long and not splitted. That is because I am not sure how I should split it. But maybe you have some hints for me.

While writing this I realized that the accept function is blocking until the client send a connect request. So should I add all procedures after the `accept()` call to the thread function?
Is my accept function unnecessary then?

I have an repo available at: https://github.com/mortytheshorty/socks

This is my project structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── socks.h
├── socks4.rfc
└── src
    ├── include
    │   ├── socket_config.h
    │   ├── socks4.h
    │   └── socks_internal.h
    ├── readFromSocket.c
    ├── sendToSocket.c
    ├── socket_configuration.c
    ├── socks_accept.c
    ├── socks_close.c
    ├── socks_connect.c
    ├── socks_init.c
    ├── socks_listen.c
    ├── socks_log.c
    ├── test
    │   ├── client.c
    │   └── server.c
    └── thread.c
```

Here the source code:

socks.h

```
//
// Created by flo on 4/18/23.
//

#ifndef SOCKS_SOCKS_H
#define SOCKS_SOCKS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


#define SOCKS4_VERSION 0x04

/* Socks types*/
enum SOCKS_TYPE {SOCKS_SERVER, SOCKS_CLIENT};


typedef struct socks_config {
    int type; // SOCKS_SERVER or SOCKS_CLIENT
    int maxconn; // maximum connections possible if SOCKS_SERVER else irgnored
    char *ip; // SOCKS_SERVER == interface the to listen on, SOCKS_CLIENT == server address to connect to
    uint16_t port; // SOCKS_SERVER == port to listen on, SOCKS_CLIENT == socks server port to connect to
    char *filename; // log file name
    uint8_t version; // socks version
} socks_config;

typedef struct socks {
    socks_config *config; // pointer to socks config
    int sock; // network socket
    char *ip; // destination ip address to connect to via socks proxy or unused as server
    uint16_t port; // destination port to connect to via socks proxy or unused as server
    FILE *log; // log file handle
} socks;

typedef struct socks_connection {
    int client_sock;
    int target_sock;
} socks_connection;

/**
 * @brief Initializes the socks structure for client and server aswell
 * 
 * @param socks socks strucuture
 * @param config socks configruation
 * @retval 0 on success
 * @retval n on failure
 */
int socks_init(socks *socks, socks_config *config);

/**
 * @brief Connectes a socks client with a remote peer via the proxy
 * 
 * @param client socks client structure
 * @param ip destination ip
 * @param port destination port
 * @retval 0 on success
 * @retval n on failure
 */
int socks_connect(socks *client, char *ip, int port);

/**
 * @brief Starts listening on configured server
 * 
 * @param proxy socks server structure
 * @retval 0 on success
 * @retval n on failure
 */
int socks_listen(socks *proxy);


/**
 * @brief Sends data of specified size to socks socket
 * 
 * @param socks socks socks structure
 * @param data data
 * @param len size of data
 * @retval n on success
 * @retval -1 on failure
 */
ssize_t socks_send(socks *socks, void *data, size_t len);

/**
 * @brief Receives data of specified size to socks socket
 * 
 * @param socks socks socks structure
 * @param data data
 * @param len size of data
 * @retval n on success
 * @retval -1 on failure
 */
ssize_t socks_recv(socks *socks, void *data, size_t len);

/**
 * @brief Destroys socks structure
 * 
 * @param socks socks strucutre
 */
void socks_destroy(socks *socks);



#endif //SOCKS_SOCKS_H
```

socket_config.h

```
#ifndef SOCKS_CONFIG_H
#define SOCKS_CONFIG_H

#include <inttypes.h>

/* not sure if I want to use it */
void socket_enable_keepalive(int sock);

/* gets ipv4 address and port form socket file descriptor */
/* NOTE: buffer and bufsz must be at least INET6_ADDRSTRLEN or bigger */
int socket_peer_addrinfo(int sock, char *buffer, size_t bufsz, uint16_t *port);

#endif
```

socks4.h

```
//
// Created by flo on 4/18/23.
//

#ifndef SOCKS_SOCKS4_H
#define SOCKS_SOCKS4_H

#include <inttypes.h>

#define PACKED __attribute__((__packed__))

#define SOCKS4_VERSION 0x04
#define SOCKS4_CMD_CONNECT 0x01
#define SOCKS4_CMD_BIND 0x02

struct PACKED socks4_request {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t cmd;
    uint16_t port; // network byte order
    uint32_t ip; // network byte order
    uint8_t userid[1];
};
typedef struct socks4_request socks4_request;


#define SOCKS4_REPLY_GRANTED 0x5A
#define SOCKS4_REPLY_FAILED 0x5B
// #define SOCKS4_REPLY_IDENT_CONNECT_FAILED 0x5C
// #define SOCKS4_REPLY_IDENT_AUTH_FAILED 0x5D

struct PACKED socks4_reply {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t code;
    uint16_t port;
    uint32_t ip;
};
typedef struct socks4_reply socks4_reply;


enum SOCKS4_ERRORS {
    SOCKS_OK,
    SOCKS_SEND_ERR,
    SOCKS_RECV_ERR,
    SOCKS_REPLY_INVAL,
    SOCKS_REQUEST_DENY,
    SOCKS_SOCKCREAT_ERR,
    SOCKS_LOGCREAT_ERR,
    SOCKS_IP_INVAL,
    SOCKS_SOCKREUSE_ERR,
    SOCKS_SERVER_BIND_ERR,
    SOCKS_CLIENT_CONNECT_ERR,
    SOCKS_SERVER_ACCEPT_ERR,
    SOCKS_SERVER_CONNECT_ERR, // server can not connect to destination
    SOCKS_LISTEN_ERR,
};

#endif //SOCKS_SOCKS4_H
```

socks_internal.h

```
#ifndef SOCKS_INTERNAL_H
#define SOCKS_INTERNAL_H

#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#include "../../include/socks.h"
#include "socket_config.h"
#include "socks4.h"


ssize_t readFromSocket(int sock, void *buf, size_t size);
ssize_t sendToSocket(int sock, void *buf, size_t size);

void *socks_connection_thread(void *pipefdsp);
int socks_accept(socks *proxy, socks_connection *conn);
int socks_log(socks *socks, const char *function, const char *fmt, ...);
#endif
```

readFromSocket.c

```
#include "include/socks_internal.h"

ssize_t readFromSocket(int sock, void *buf, size_t size)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    ssize_t num_bytes, total = 0;

    while (total < size) {
        num_bytes = recv(sock, &pbuf[total], size-total, 0);
        if (num_bytes <= 0) {
            if ((num_bytes < 0) && ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))) {
                break;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        total += num_bytes;
    }

    return total;
}
```

sendToSocket.c

```
#include "include/socks_internal.h"

ssize_t sendToSocket(int sock, void *buf, size_t size)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    ssize_t num_bytes, total = 0;

    while (total < size) {
        num_bytes = send(sock, &pbuf[total], size-total, 0);
        if (num_bytes < 0) {
            if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                break;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        total += num_bytes;
    }

    return total;
}
```

socket_config.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define check(expr) if (!(expr)) { perror(#expr); kill(0, SIGTERM); }

void socket_enable_keepalive(int sock) {
    int yes = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &yes, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int idle = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idle, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int interval = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &interval, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int maxpkt = 10;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &maxpkt, sizeof(int)) != -1);
}


void *get_in_addr(const struct sockaddr_storage *storage) {

    if( storage->ss_family == AF_INET) // IPv4 address
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)storage)->sin_addr);
    // else IPv6 address
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)storage)->sin6_addr);
}

int socket_peer_addrinfo(int sock, char *buffer, size_t bufsz, uint16_t *port)
{
    if(bufsz != INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) {
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_storage inaddr;
    socklen_t inaddr_len = sizeof(inaddr);
    
    getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, &inaddr_len);

    if(inet_ntop(inaddr.ss_family, get_in_addr(&inaddr), buffer, inaddr_len) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(port) {
        *port = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&inaddr)->sin_port);
    }

    return 0;
}

int socket_local_addrinfo(int sock, char *buffer, size_t bufsz, uint16_t *port)
{
    if(bufsz < INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) {
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_storage inaddr;
    socklen_t inaddr_len = sizeof(inaddr);
    
    getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, &inaddr_len);

    if(inet_ntop(inaddr.ss_family, get_in_addr(&inaddr), buffer, inaddr_len) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    

    if(port) {
        *port = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&inaddr)->sin_port);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

socks_accept.c

```
#include "include/socks_internal.h"


int target_connect(socks *proxy, socks4_request *req, int client_sock, int *target_sock)
{
    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    uint16_t port;
    socks4_reply reply;
    struct sockaddr_in inaddr;
    memset(&inaddr, 0, sizeof(inaddr));

    inaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = req->ip;
    inaddr.sin_port = req->port;

    *target_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(target_sock < 0) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to create remote peer socket.");
        return SOCKS_SOCKCREAT_ERR; // SOCKS_SERVER_TARGET_SOCKET_CREATE_ERROR
    }

    socket_peer_addrinfo(client_sock, ip, sizeof(ip), &port);
    // we try to connect to the remote peer for the client
    if(connect(*target_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, sizeof(inaddr)) != 0) {
        reply.version = SOCKS4_VERSION;
        reply.code = SOCKS4_REPLY_FAILED;
        reply.ip = inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr;
        reply.port = inaddr.sin_port;
        
        if(sendToSocket(client_sock, &reply, sizeof(reply)) != sizeof(reply)) {
            socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to send reply about failed connect to %s:%d", ip, port);
            return SOCKS_SEND_ERR;
        }

        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to connect to remote peer '%s:%d'", ip, port);

        return SOCKS_SERVER_CONNECT_ERR; // SOCKS_SERVER_TARGET_CONNECT_ERROR
    }

    socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "CONNECT from %s:%d to %s:%d", ip, port, inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*) &req->ip), ntohs(req->port));
    return SOCKS_OK;
}

int socks_accept(socks *proxy, socks_connection *conn)
{
    if(proxy->config->type != SOCKS_SERVER) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "can not listen to socks handle. socks handle is a client");
    }
    
    socks4_request request;
    socks4_reply reply;

    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    uint16_t port;
    int target_sock = -1;
    int client_sock = -1;
    int rc = 0;
    
    client_sock = accept(proxy->sock, NULL, NULL);
    if(client_sock < 0) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "socks_accept: failed to accept connection from %s", "unknown");
        return SOCKS_SERVER_ACCEPT_ERR; // SOCKS_SERVER_ACCEPT_ERROR see: errno
    }


    socket_peer_addrinfo(client_sock, ip, sizeof(ip), &port);
    socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "connection from %s:%d", ip, port);

    if(readFromSocket(client_sock, &request, sizeof(request)) != sizeof(request)) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to receive request from '%s:%d'", ip, port);
        close(client_sock);
        return SOCKS_RECV_ERR; // SOCKS_SERVER_RECV_ERROR 
    }
    
    if(request.userid != 0) {
        // identifaction protocol code
    }


    rc = target_connect(proxy, &request, client_sock, &target_sock);
    if( rc ) {
        return SOCKS_SERVER_CONNECT_ERR;
    }


    // build the reply
    reply.version = SOCKS4_VERSION;
    reply.code = SOCKS4_REPLY_GRANTED;
    reply.port = request.port;
    reply.ip = request.ip;

    // send it back to the client
    if(sendToSocket(client_sock, &reply, sizeof(reply)) != sizeof(reply)) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to send reply about successful connect to '%s:%d'", "unknown", 0);
        close(client_sock);
        return SOCKS_SEND_ERR; // SOCKS_SERVER_SEND_ERROR
    }

    
    conn->client_sock = client_sock;
    conn->target_sock = target_sock;

    return 0;
}
```

socks_close.c

```
#include "include/socks_internal.h"

void socks_destroy(socks *socks_handle)
{
    close(socks_handle->sock);
    socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "closing connection");
    if(socks_handle->log) {
        fclose(socks_handle->log);
    }
}
```

socks_connect.c

```
#include "include/socks_internal.h"

int socks_connect(socks *client, char *ip, int port) {
    
    client->ip = ip;
    client->port = port;

    ssize_t ret = 0;
    socks4_request request;

    request.version = SOCKS4_VERSION;
    request.cmd = SOCKS4_CMD_CONNECT;
    request.port = htons((short) port);
    request.ip = inet_addr(ip);
    request.userid[0] = 0x00;

    if((ret = sendToSocket(client->sock, &request, sizeof(request))) != sizeof(request)) {
        socks_log(client, __FUNCTION__, "failed to send CONNECT request");
        return SOCKS_SEND_ERR;
    }
    
    socks4_reply reply;

    if((ret = readFromSocket(client->sock, &reply, sizeof(reply))) != sizeof(reply)) {
        socks_log(client, __FUNCTION__, "failed to receive reply from socks server '%s:%d'", client->config->ip, client->config->port);
        return SOCKS_RECV_ERR;
    }

    switch(reply.code) {
        case SOCKS4_REPLY_GRANTED:
            socks_log(client, __FUNCTION__, "connection to '%s:%d' established", client->ip, client->port);
            return 0;

        case SOCKS4_REPLY_FAILED:
            socks_log(client, __FUNCTION__, "connection to '%s:%d' denied", client->ip, client->port);
            return SOCKS_REQUEST_DENY;

        default:
            socks_log(client, __FUNCTION__, "received unsupported reply code '%d' (X'%x')", reply.code, reply.code);
            return SOCKS_REPLY_INVAL;
    }

}
```

socks_init.c

```
//
// Created by flo on 4/17/23.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include "include/socks_internal.h"


int socks_init(socks *socks_handle, socks_config *config)
{
    int rc = 0;
    int on = 1;

    socks_handle->config = config;

    if(config->filename)
    {
        socks_handle->log = fopen(config->filename, "w");

        if( !socks_handle->log ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: can't open logfile '%s'\n", config->filename);
            return SOCKS_LOGCREAT_ERR;
        }

    }

    socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "Socks%d-%s started.", config->version, (config->type == SOCKS_SERVER) ? "Server" : "Client");

    // initialize socks main socket
    socks_handle->sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socks_handle->sock < 0)
    {
        socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "failed to create socket");
        return SOCKS_SOCKCREAT_ERR; // SOCKS_SOCKET_CREATION_ERROR
    }


    /* this is SOCKS VERSION dependent */
    struct sockaddr_in inaddr;
    memset(&inaddr, 0, sizeof(inaddr));

    inaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inaddr.sin_port = htons((uint16_t) config->port);
    inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(config->ip);
    if(inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "failed to parse ip address %s", config->ip);
        return SOCKS_IP_INVAL; // SOCKS_WRONG_IP_ADDRESS
    }

    /* if server, bind address to socket and set it reusable */
    if(config->type == SOCKS_SERVER)
    {
        rc = setsockopt(socks_handle->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));
        if(rc < 0) {
            socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "failed to enable reuse of socket address");
            return SOCKS_SOCKREUSE_ERR;
        }

        if( bind(socks_handle->sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, sizeof(inaddr)) != 0 )
        {
            socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "failed to bind %s to socket.", config->ip);
            return SOCKS_SERVER_BIND_ERR; // SOCKS_BIND_ERROR
        }

    }

    /* if client, try to connect to proxy server */
    else if(config->type == SOCKS_CLIENT)
    {
        if(connect(socks_handle->sock, (struct sockaddr*)&inaddr, sizeof(inaddr)) != 0)
        {
            socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "failed to connect to socks server %s", config->ip);
            return SOCKS_CLIENT_CONNECT_ERR; // SOCKS_CLIENT_CONNECT_ERROR
        }
        socks_log(socks_handle, __FUNCTION__, "connected to socker server %s:%d", config->ip, config->port);
    }

    return 0;
}

/* sends data via proxy server */
ssize_t socks_send(socks *client, void *data, size_t len)
{
    return sendToSocket(client->sock, data, len);
}

/* reads data from proxy server */
ssize_t socks_recv(socks *client, void *data, size_t len)
{   
    return readFromSocket(client->sock, data, len);
}
```

socks_listen.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "include/socks_internal.h"


int socks_listen(socks *proxy)
{
    if(proxy->config->type != SOCKS_SERVER) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "can not listen to socks handle. socks handle is a client");
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_t thread;
    socks_connection conn;
    int conidx = 0;

    if(listen(proxy->sock, proxy->config->maxconn) != 0) {
        socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to listen on %s", proxy->config->ip);
        return SOCKS_LISTEN_ERR; // SOCKS_LISTEN_ERROR see: errno
    }

    socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "listening on '%s:%d'", proxy->config->ip, proxy->config->port);

    for(;;) {
        socks_connection conn;
        int ret = socks_accept(proxy, &conn);
        if(ret < 0) {
            // SOCKS_ACCEPT ERROR
            socks_log(proxy, __FUNCTION__, "failed to accept connection from %s", "unkown");
            continue;
        }

        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, socks_connection_thread, &conn);
        conidx++;
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

socks_log.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "include/socks_internal.h"

int socks_log(socks *socks, const char *function, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    
    if(socks->log) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, fmt);
        time_t now = time(NULL); // get current time
        char buffer[128];
        struct tm tnow;

        gmtime_r(&now, &tnow); // create UTC time

        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%Z", &tnow); // create UTC time format string

        fprintf(socks->log, "%s: ", buffer); // log timestamp
        vfprintf(socks->log, fmt, args); // log message

        if(errno) { // if errno is set, log calling function with error string
            fprintf(socks->log, "%s: %s", function, strerror(errno));
        }
        va_end(args);

        fputc('\n', socks->log);
        fflush(socks->log);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thread.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <poll.h>

#include "include/socks_internal.h"

#define MAX_SOCKETS 2

#define DEFAULT_TIMEOUT (3 * 60 * 1000)

#define CLIENT_POLL 0
#define REMOTE_POLL 1

int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

void *socks_connection_thread(void *pipefd) {

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    socks_connection conn = *(socks_connection*) pipefd;
    int rc = 0;

    int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
    /* two pollfd's for listening on remote peer and client connection for events */
    struct pollfd pfds[MAX_SOCKETS];
    nfds_t nfds = MAX_SOCKETS;

    uint8_t client_buf[4096];
    size_t client_buf_size = 0;

    uint8_t target_buf[4096];
    size_t target_buf_size = 0;
    
    ssize_t num_bytes;

    memset(&pfds, 0, sizeof(pfds));

    /* set sockets to non blocking */
    int opt = 1;
    ioctl(conn.client_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);
    ioctl(conn.target_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);

    
    while(true) {
        

        pfds[CLIENT_POLL].fd = conn.client_sock;
        pfds[CLIENT_POLL].events = POLLIN;

        pfds[REMOTE_POLL].fd = conn.target_sock;
        pfds[REMOTE_POLL].events = POLLIN;


        /* waiting for some events */
        rc = poll(pfds, MAX_SOCKETS, timeout);
        if(rc < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "poll() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        if(rc == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "poll() timed out. End Connection\n");
            break;
        }


        /* there is something to read form the client side */
        if(pfds[CLIENT_POLL].revents & POLLIN)
        {

            num_bytes = readFromSocket(conn.client_sock, &client_buf[client_buf_size], sizeof(client_buf)-client_buf_size);
            if(num_bytes < 0) break; // client connection lost
            if(num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("read from client: %s (%ld)\n", client_buf, num_bytes);
                client_buf_size += num_bytes;
                pfds[REMOTE_POLL].revents = POLLOUT;
            }
        }
        /* there is something to read from the remote side */
        else if(pfds[REMOTE_POLL].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            //printf("Got data from remote.\n");
            num_bytes = readFromSocket(conn.target_sock, target_buf, sizeof(target_buf));
            if (num_bytes < 0) break; // remote connection lost
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("read from peer: %s (%ld)\n", target_buf, num_bytes);
                target_buf_size += num_bytes;
                pfds[CLIENT_POLL].revents = POLLOUT;
            }
        }

        /* client has data to receive */
        if(pfds[CLIENT_POLL].revents & POLLOUT) {
            num_bytes = sendToSocket(conn.client_sock, target_buf, target_buf_size);
            if (num_bytes < 0) break;
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("forward to client: %s (%ld)\n", target_buf, num_bytes);
                // remove the sent bytes...
                target_buf_size -= num_bytes;
                memmove(client_buf, &client_buf[num_bytes], client_buf_size);

            } 
        } else if(pfds[REMOTE_POLL].revents & POLLOUT) {
            num_bytes = sendToSocket(conn.target_sock, client_buf, num_bytes);
            if(num_bytes < 0) break;
            if(num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("forward to remote peer: %s (%ld)\n", client_buf, num_bytes);
                // remove the sent bytes...
                client_buf_size -= num_bytes;
                memmove(target_buf, &target_buf[num_bytes], target_buf_size);
            }

        }

        else {
            // unexpected event result appeared so close the connection
            break;
        }

    }

    // all done
    close(conn.client_sock);
    close(conn.target_sock);
    printf("Thread terminating\n");

}
```

Comment: If you have a GitHub or Bitbucket repository it might help to provide a link to it so that we can reproduce your work easily. It would be nice to have access to your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: I wasn't sure to do that because I thought it is not allowed. But I will create a github repo.

Comment: Rather than `struct pollfd pfds[MAX_SOCKETS]; ... memset(&pfds, 0, sizeof(pfds));`, simplify: `struct pollfd pfds[MAX_SOCKETS] = { 0 };`.

Comment: Someone told me that in another question but I don't know it works with arrays too. Is this a compiler feature or a C feature and does this have a name? Never saw that, where can I read about thouse nifty things?

Comment: @mortytheshorty "a C feature".  [Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)#Initializer).

Comment: @mortytheshorty, Curious, why the unneeded cast in `char *pbuf = (char*) buf;`? Trying to maintain C++ capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Key points

> [...] I would like to have a review of my:
>
> - project structure

It looks sensible to me. You could create a doc/ directory where you put in any documentation like socks4.rfc.

> - filenaming/code splitting

What you did is fine. However, it would also have been acceptable to just have a socks.c file that contains all the code that's now distributed over several socks_*.c files, and to put utility functions like `readFromSocket()`, `writeToSocket()` and `socks_connection_thread()` in a utils.c file. It's a matter of taste. Nowadays compilers and code editors deal with large files very well.

I would rename include/socks.h to include/socks4.h though, since it really is SOCKS4-specific.

> - naming/design of structures

That's fine. I would however not bother with `PACKED`. The variables are already layed out in such a way that they are naturally packed, there is no need to force that in any way. The only issue is the `uint8_t userid[1]` field. It's not really 1 byte, it's actually a variable length field that you are currently not handling in your code, I think you assume it will always be just a NUL-byte? I would write another function to read variable-length, NUL-terminated strings from a socket.

> - error handling

You are doing it, but it's not consistent. In some functions you `return` an error code, in others you do `kill(0, SIGTERM)`. I would make it so everything returns an error code, killing the process is quite rude and prevents the caller from dealing with errors in a better way.

Also consider which errors really need to be dealt with. So what if `SO_KEEPALIVE` cannot be set? It will not prevent you from making a connection to the SOCKS server. In this case, ignoring the error might be the best approach. You could consider logging a warning though.

If a system call returns `EAGAIN`, it should be safe to immediately retry it again. So instead of doing a `break`, it might be better to `continue`. The same is not true for `EWOULDBLOCK`.

> - and of course the code.

Others have already commented on that, and I don't have much to add, but see below.

> - handling multiple connections (thread for each session? threadpool?)

There are various trade-offs here. You could do it without threads, and just `poll()` *all* the filedescriptors. You don't get the benefit of using multiple cores if you have lots of traffic to deal with, but on the other hand, you don't have to deal with any thread-related issues.

One thread per session is fine, however if you have lots of connections, you have to consider the per-thread overhead. In particular, each thread will need memory for its stack, and that can be quite a lot (something like 2 MB on Linux). On 32-bit systems, that could cause you to run out of (virtual) memory quite fast. You can use pthread attributes to start threads with a smaller stack to work around this.

A thread pool would be the most complicated solution. Are you going to distribute connections over the threads? What if one threads gets all the active connections and the others get relatively inactive ones? Or is every thread going to `poll()` all the sockets? This can cause all threads to wake up every time there is some activity. Or do you want one thread that `poll()s` all sockets and then wakes up one or more threads as required to handle the actual data arriving on a connection? That requires a lot of synchronization.

If you want it to be multi-threaded, then I would go for one thread per connection. It's the simplest, it's quite efficient, and if you keep the stack space in mind you'll probably be fine.

## Type safety

> I tried to create a flexible `socks_config` and `socks` structure but I am not sure if I succeeded. I really want to avoid having `socks4_client` and `socks4_server` to achive a simple and small interface for the user, where the functions returns if it is the wrong "object type".

But now you rely on your code to check if the right "object type" is passed in. Whereas if you have separate `struct`s for this, the compiler can check at compile time whether you pass the right type of object to a function.

Note that you can nest structs, so you can reduce code duplication like so:

```
typedef struct socks_common_config {
    char *ip;
    uint16_t port;
    char *filename;
    uint8_t version;
} socks_common_config;

typedef struct socks_server_config {
    int maxconn;
    socks_common_config common;
} socks_server_config;

typedef struct socks_client_config {
    socks_common_config common;
} socks_client_config;
```

## No need for `struct sock`

Instead of having a `socks_init()` function and then `socks_connect()` and `socks_listen()`, why not pass the configuration directly to the latter two functions?

```
int socks_connect(socks_client_config *config, char *ip, int port);
int socks_listen(socks_server_config *config);
```

There is no `socks` struct necessary anymore. The `int` returns by `socks_connect()` is just a filedescriptor of the established proxy connection (or -1 in case of errors).

Comment: Thanks, this helps alot. Especially the fact that there is no need for `struct socks`. I will try to rewrite it by having this all of this in mind. Because I thought sticking to the threaded way I wrote a  thread library in the last days which looks quite powerful to me. While writing this library I found an acceptable way for debugging and I am very sorry  that I did not use it earlier to help you review the code[.](https://github.com:mortytheshorty/thread.git)

Answer (score 5):

Just a small review.

---

[logging time]

**Add error checking**

Functions like `time(), gmtime_r(), strftime()` all could return an error indication.  Use it.

**Use `Z`**

Using `"-%Z"` to append a `'-'` and then the time zone name is curious.  I fond nothing in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to support that format.

What is common is to append a `"Z"` for UTC times.

**Buffer size**

A generous buffer size is good, yet we could reduce it a ways and still maintain a 2x factor.

**Standard code**

`gmtime_r()` is not part of the standard C library.  The alterative below uses `gmtime()` for example.

**Alternate code**

```
    #define TIME_BUF_LEN (11 /* year */ + 5*2 /* mdHMS */ + 6 /* separators */ )
    char buffer[TIME_BUF_LEN * 2 + 1];

    time_t now = time(NULL); // get current time
    if (now == -1) {
      strcpy(buffer, "Unknown time");
    } else {
      struct tm *tm_now = gmtime(&now);
      if (tm_now == NULL) {
        strcpy(buffer, "Unknown time");
      } else {
        if (strftime(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tm_now) == 0) {
          strcpy(buffer, "Unknown time");
        }
      }
    }
```

---

[Edit]

**Latent Bug**

In `sendToSocket()`, code tests `errno` after `send()`, yet does not clear `errno` first.  Better code would zero it, even if in this application, `sendToSocket()` is not called with `errno != 0` to allow for greater future use. `send()`, like many functions, does not zero `errno` on success.

```
    errno = 0; // Add
    num_bytes = send(sock, &pbuf[total], size-total, 0);
    if (num_bytes < 0) {
        if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
```

Alternatively, `sendToSocket()` should be documented that it should not get called with `errno != 0`.

Comment: 1. So it is okay to not return an error if one function fails? Can I change the return type to `void` then?
2.  I don't know why I've added the `'-'`, I will stick to your format string. 
3. Of course... I know you told me to get rid of magic numbers.
4. As I want to add logging support to the threads, I wanted a thread safe method but I can get it done with a mutex I think. If I do so, should I call `pthread_mutex_lock()` after the `time()`-call to at least get the correct time?

Comment: @mortytheshorty 1) There are many ways to handle/report an error.  Code here simply uses `strcpy(buffer, "Unknown time");`.  You may instead want return from `socks_log()` with an error code. Your call.  4) Re: thread-safe.  Use `gmtime_r()` and forego high portability.

Comment: Still problems to decide how to handle error properly but I thinks this comes with time.

Comment: @mortytheshorty Guideline: Lower level code should return error.  Upper level code can exit with an error message.  In-between, its up to you.

Answer (score 5):

**Add guards:**

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define PACKED __attribute__((__packed__))
#else 
#define PACKED /* If only */
#endif /* __GNUC__ || __clang__
```

**Cast not needed:**

```
// char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
char *pbuf = buf;
```

There's an implicit conversion to and from a `void *` in C.

**Reduce duplication:**

```
void socket_enable_keepalive(int sock) {
#if 0
    int yes = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &yes, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int idle = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idle, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int interval = 1;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &interval, sizeof(int)) != -1);

    int maxpkt = 10;
    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &maxpkt, sizeof(int)) != -1);
#endif

struct option {
        int level;
        int opt_name;
        const void *opt_val;
    } const options[] = {
        { SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (int[]) { 1 } },
        { IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, (int[]) { 10 } },
        { IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, (int[]) { 1 } },
        { IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, (int[]) { 1 } },
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_CARDINALITY (options); i++) {
         check (setsockopt (slave_fd, options[i].level, options[i].opt_name,
                options[i].opt_val, sizeof (int)) != -1);
    }
```

`readFromSocket()` and `sendToSocket()` can be single macro:

```
#define gen_func(_name_, _calling__) \
ssize_t _name_(int sock, void *buf, size_t size) \
{   char *pbuf = buf; \
    ssize_t num_bytes, total = 0; \
                                  \
    while (total < size) { \
        num_bytes = _calling_(sock, &pbuf[total], size-total, 0); \
        if (num_bytes <= 0) { \
            if ((num_bytes < 0) && ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))) { \
                break; \
            } \       
            return -1; \
        } \
        total += num_bytes; \
    } \
    return total; } \

gen_func(readFromSocket, recv);
gen_func(sendToSocket, send);

/* There might be a bug in the above code. I didn't test it. */
```

The same can be done for `socket_peer_addrinfo()` and `socket_local_addrinfo()`.

In `sendToSocket()`, we should be checking for `if (num_bytes <= 0)` instead of `if (num_bytes < 0)`.

**Check the return values of all library/system calls:**

```
/* Why do these go unchecked? */
getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, &inaddr_len);
getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, &inaddr_len);
ioctl(conn.client_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);
ioctl(conn.target_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);

/* And all the calls to close(), though you may forego checking them. */
```

I'd prefer using `fcntl()` instead of `ioctl()`.

**Simplify initialization:**

```
#if 0
    struct sockaddr_in inaddr;
    memset(&inaddr, 0, sizeof(inaddr));

    inaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = req->ip;
    inaddr.sin_port = req->port
#else  
    struct sockaddr_in inaddr = { .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_addr.s_addr = req->ip, .sin_port = req->port };
#endif

#if 0
    socks4_request request;

    request.version = SOCKS4_VERSION;
    request.cmd = SOCKS4_CMD_CONNECT;
    request.port = htons((short) port);
    request.ip = inet_addr(ip);
    request.userid[0] = 0x00;
#else
    socks4_request request = { .version = SOCKS4_VERSION, .cmd = SOCKS4_CMD_CONNECT, ...};
#endif

// In at least 2 more places.
```

**Declare variables where used:**

```
#if 0 

    socks4_reply reply;
    ....
    if(connect(*target_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, sizeof(inaddr)) != 0) {
        reply.version = SOCKS4_VERSION;
        reply.code = SOCKS4_REPLY_FAILED;
        reply.ip = inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr;
        reply.port = inaddr.sin_port;
#else
   if (connect(*target_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &inaddr, sizeof(inaddr)) != 0) {   
       socks4_reply reply = { .version = SOCKS4_VERSION, .code = SOCKS4_REPLY_FAILED, .ip = inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, .port = inaddr.sin_port };
#endif
```

It's cumbersome to go to the top of the function to see what a variable was declared as.

**Warning: *Multiple declarations of variable `timeout`*:**

```
/* It was first declared here. */
int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

void *socks_connection_thread(void *pipefd) {

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    socks_connection conn = *(socks_connection*) pipefd;
    int rc = 0;

    int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
    /* Why declare it here again? */
```

---

**Minor:**

- Don't leave so many linefeeds; they don't grow on trees.
- Run spell-check on the code.
- `socks_accept()` should only accept a connection. It shouldn't read from the socket, build a reply, and send it back to the client.
- This error message below is not very helpful. Consider calling `perror()` or `sterror()`.

```
fprintf(stderr, "error: can't open logfile '%s'\n", config->filename);
```

- Be consistent with your bracing.
- Don't bother returning an error code if you're going to leave it unchecked. `socket_peer_addrinfo()` should have it's value checked.
- I'd rework the logging utility to build a string with `snprintf()` and make a single call to `fprintf()`/`fputs()`.

Comment: 1. Only `#ifdef __GNUC__ || __clang__` did not work as I got `warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive` messages.  But this works `#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)`.
2. Fixed.
3. Inpiring solution, thank you.
4. Fixed
5. Fixed.

With linefeeds you mean empty lines? I ran `"-pedantic" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wconversion"` and fixed anything I think. Except the usage of macro `__FUNCTION__`

Comment: I edited the first snippet. Yes, by linefeeds, I meant empty lines. Is there any reason why you're not using the standard `__func__` instead of `__FUNCTION__`? What's the warning, though? And what do we need `_GNU_SOURCE` for?

Comment: The warning was `warning: ISO C does not support ‘__FUNCTION__’ predefined identifier [-Wpedantic]`. I used it because I just remembered it but I switched to `__func__`. I created a macro which inserts `__func__` and now the build runs without any complains. `_GNU_SOURCE` was used because I first wanted to use `struct addrinfo` but as Socks4 does only support IPv4 I just forgot to remove it. Will use it if I try on Socks5.

Comment: Why should `sendToSocket()` use `if(num_bytes <= 0)`? In the manpage they say it returns -1. Does't tcp allow 0 length data send?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to check for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3081952/20017547

Comment: `num_bytes == 0` in itself in not an error.  Any `num_bytes >=0` and less than the number sent needs handling.

Comment: I would avoid the macro `gen_func()`. Just make a helper function that implements evertyhing and takes a boolean to choose between `recv()` and `send()`, and then create `readFromSocket()` and `writeToSocket()` that just call that helper function. The compiler can inline and optimize that.